# Deezer android sdk UI freeze during login

Tags: deezer

I implemented the Deeezer android SDK in my application and I got a user who can't log into its Deezer account on its Motorola Razr I. The login UI freezes on this page and the application restarts. He doesn't encounter the issue on its other devices.

The SDK version I use is 0.9.3

Here is a screenshot of the page where the application freezes.

[image: Deezer UI login]
What kind of information would help identify the issue?

**Edit**

Here is the source code :

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity
{
    protected static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"basic_access", "manage_library", "delete_library", "listening_history", "manage_community"};

    // DeezerConnect object
    private DeezerConnect   m_deezerConnect;

    // Handle connection callbacks.
    private DialogHandler   m_dialogHandler     = new DialogHandler();

    // if the authentication failed, retry once
    private boolean         m_firstTry          = true;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        m_deezerConnect = new DeezerConnectImpl(getString(R.string.deezer_app_id));

        SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();

        AlertDialog.Builder deezerAuthDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        deezerAuthDialog.setTitle(R.string.deezer_authentication);
        deezerAuthDialog.setMessage(R.string.enter_deezer_credentials);
        deezerAuthDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                connectToDeezer(m_dialogHandler);
            }
        });

        deezerAuthDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        deezerAuthDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });

        deezerAuthDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Connects to Deezer web services using an injectable DialogListener listener.
     * @param listener event listener that will be notified of the connection progress.
     */
    private void connectToDeezer(final DialogListener listener)
    {
        m_deezerConnect.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, listener);
    }

    /** Handle DeezerConnect callbacks. */
    private class DialogHandler implements DialogListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final Bundle values)
        {
            SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();
            sessionStore.save(m_deezerConnect, LoginActivity.this);

            LoginActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeezerError(final DeezerError deezerError)
        {
            Log.e(DeemoteGlobals.TAG, "DialogError error during login" , deezerError );
            LoginActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final DialogError dialogError)
        {
            // the api returns an error while the authentication succeed, so we force a retry once
            int errorCode = dialogError.getErrorCode();
            if (errorCode == -10 && m_firstTry)
            {
                    m_firstTry = false;
                    connectToDeezer(m_dialogHandler);
                    return;
                }

            Log.e(DeemoteGlobals.TAG, "DialogError error during login", dialogError);
            }

            LoginActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
            LoginActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onOAuthException(OAuthException oAuthException)
        {
            LoginActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the 0.10.10 SDK which is available since the beginning of the year? Maybe you could send us your code surrounding the call to the authentication page?

Comment: This SDK is still in Beta. Do you think it's production ready?

Comment: It should be marked as production ready in the next few days, so it's safe to use it. Do you have any error message in the Log Cat window when the application restarts ?

Comment: I performed the sdk update. I'm waiting for the user feedback. I'll try to get the log cat from him if it still doesn't work.